# Binary relation with a for all (x,y)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to trace the graph considering this :

$$A = \Big( 1, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{27}, \frac{1}{4}, 3, \frac{1}{36}, 2, \frac{2}{9}, \frac{9}{4}, 5 \Big)$$

$$\forall x,y \in A : xRy ⇔ ∃z \in Z; \frac{x}{y} = 3^z$$

What does it mean? Do I have to verify if $ (1,1), (1, \frac{1}{3}), (1, \frac{1}{27}), ..., (x,y) $ satisfy $ \frac{x}{y} = 3^z $ ?

Comment: Yes, here's a hint though, multiply everything by $27 \times 4$ and write their prime factorisations to make life a bit easier

Comment: I'm not sure to understand why you would multiply by 27 * 4 ? Could you explain me, please ? thanks ! - Nevermind, understood.

Comment: You don't need to, you can leave everything as fractions.  I just chose $27 \times 4$ to make everything an integer.  Either way, you just need the exponent of primes other than $3$ to be the same for $x$ to be related to $y$.  Write everything out as prime factors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means $x$ is related to $y$ (or $xRy$) if there exists a $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ (that may depend on $x$ and $y$) (and I assume that $Z$ in your question is the set of integers) such that $\frac{x}{y} = 3^z$. So, to check whether or not $1R1$, you have $x=1$, $y=1$, and you ask yourself, "Is there a $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\frac{1}{1} = 3^z$?." The answer is yes ($z=0$), and you conclude, "Hey $1R1$". How about $1R2$? You ask whether there is a $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\frac{1}{2} = 3^z$. Now, the answer is no, and you continue like this..